# Is a function which inverse image sends $G_\delta$ and $F_\sigma$ sets to $G_\delta$ and $F_\sigma$ sets continuous?

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $X,Y$ be two topological spaces. It is known that any function $f:X\to Y$ which is continuous satisfies $f^{-1}(A)$ is a $G_\delta$ set (resp. a $F_\sigma$ set) for all $G_\delta$ set (resp. $F_\sigma$ set) $A\subseteq Y$.

Is the converse true? If not, is there a counterexample?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f(x)=0$ for $ x<0$ and $1$ for $x \geq 0$. Then $f^{-1}(A)$ is  a $G_{\delta}$ as well as an $F_{\sigma}$ for any set $A$ but $f$ is not continuous.